# Prevent "fake-client" for ios app

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication

We have an android and ios app which sends data and commands to a server with http webservice. How can i prevent the possibility, that fake-clients also can send something to the server? How can I determine serversidely if the data/command really comes from our apps.

Comment: You might want to remove that Android tag, as it's misleading.

Comment: We also have a android app but I forgot to write it down.

Comment: is there anything still unclear for you or is the question answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant really prevent it. There are several techniques to make it harder for people abusing your services.

A simple check can be to check the user agent calling your webservice. Another pretty common one is to use a simple authentication via user/password authentication on your webserver. The username and password will be embedded into your app.

If you have enough time you should think about using a combination of this two methods plus authentication with a embedded ssl certificate. You simply could add this to your project and if someone really want to abuse your service, he have to extract this certificate atleast form your application.

There are some other useful techniques but you cant prevent reverse engineering or network sniffing.

Sincerely,
fuxx

Comment: in addition to that you could generate random authentication tokens periodically on the server and send it to the client via push - say every hour. The client would then have to use this token to call the web service.

Answer (score 3):

The most robust solution is not to try. Techniques like DasFuxx's answer suggests can make it faintly harder, but someone can always decompile your application and get whatever secrets you have embedded in it.

Instead, follow the rule of multiplayer game development:

> **Don't trust the client.**

Don't think about your application as the user interface. Think about *your network protocol/API* as being the user interface; then design *that* interface so that it cannot be abused.

It may not be possible to do so completely, but insofar as you succeed, you have true security (rather than fighting the same losing battle as DRM systems).

Answer (score 2):

I would implement oAuth. See [the following link](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/) for more information on how to implement such a solution.

Comment: I do not see how using oAuth could solve this issue, as you cannot assume a mobile app is capable of keeping secret of its client secret (credential) - you could exact the app's client credential and fake it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's that simple...